# Does Cassandra create hints for non idempotent operations?

Tags: cassandra

There are some points about hinted hand off and non-idempotent operations that I know:

- WriteTimeout during request operation leads to a hint creation
- WriteTimeout doesn't mean that data was written but it doesn't mean that data was not written also
- Hint will replay of failed operation in future
- Non-idempotent operation (insert into list or update a counter) can't be applied multiple times without changing the result beyond the initial application

For example, I want to add item to some list in my table. I have replication factor = 2 and try to perform the query with consistency level = one.
But I'm getting WriteTimeoutException. 
Will be a hint for this operation stored and replayed again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell there's only a distinction between whether counters are involved or not in an update when creating hints. Updates to counters should not be hinted, while other regular operations (such as list appends) will.

> For example, I want to add item to some list in my table. I have replication factor = 2 and try to perform the query with consistency level = one. But I'm getting WriteTimeoutException. Will be a hint for this operation stored and replayed again?

I'd say in the typical case yes.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. May be you can point me to some documentation about it? I can't find anything except one line in https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/Counters: >If a write fails unexpectedly (timeout or loss of connection to the coordinator node) the client will not know if the operation has been performed. A retry can result in an over count

Comment: I was directly looking into the source code. But your right, there doesn't seem to be a lot of information how this works in detail in the docs or anywhere.